# Jacoco Coverage in Multi-Module Gradle Project Not Including Submodules

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I am developing a multi-module Gradle (8.7) project, structured such that one module acts as the main application, while the others are libraries used by this application. All unit tests are located within the application module. Although these tests cover code paths in the library modules, Jacoco does not seem to generate coverage reports for these submodules, leading to inaccurately low coverage metrics.
Here is the structure:

```
repository-root/
└── application/
    ├── app/
    │   ├── src/
    │   │   ├── main/
    │   │   │   └── java/
    │   │   └── test/
    │   └── build.gradle.kts
    ├── common/
    │   ├── src/
    │   │   └── main/
    │   │       └── java/
    │   └── build.gradle.kts
    └── build.gradle.kts
```

Issue:
Main Problem: Despite having tests that cover library module code, Jacoco's reports only reflect coverage for the application module.
Goal: Achieve a coverage report that accurately includes data from all modules, reflecting the true coverage achieved through tests run in the application module.

I tried to include coverage for one of the library modules (:common) by configuring the jacocoTestReport task in app/build.gradle.kts in the application module's build.gradle as follows:

```
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    val common = project(":common")
    dependsOn(tasks.test)
    dependsOn(common.tasks.test)
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        files("$buildDir/classes/java/main"),
        files("${common.buildDir}/classes/java/main"))
    sourceDirectories.setFrom(
        files("${projectDir}src/main/java"),
        files("${common.projectDir}/src/main/java"))
    executionData.setFrom(
        files("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec"),
        files("${common.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"))
    reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
        csv.required.set(false)
        html.required.set(true)
    }
}
```

I want to specify that I found this solution on some forum, but no test.exec is generated in my common module. So also other solutions like generate an aggregated RootReport that I found on other question maybe won't be suitable for my case.